# Windows script opening cmd and running a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

So i'm trying to write a script which checks if the cmd is with administrative privileges. If it is I just ran the command - which is a jar file. If it isn't what I did was create a link to the cmd and in that link I made it always run as administrator.

The problem is that after it runs the command it opens the second cmd as administrator but then the command needs to be written again. Is there any chance to save the command written and as the second cmd opens run it?

```
net session >nul
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
    java -jar %~dp0/myjar.jar%*
) else (
    echo Administrative permissions required
    cmdadmin.lnk
)
```

cmdadmin.lnk is as I said a link to cmd which in the advanced properties I set as run as administrator. 
Now what I want is to pass a command when opening the link. Is it possible?

Comment: Please post your script. Your question is quite confusing. And in engish a console's personal pronoun is "it" as it is an object. Not "he" or "she".

Comment: Why not always just always start the administrative console?

Comment: This script is gonna be used from the cmd and by many people. I want to make sure everyone opens the cmd with administrative privileges and if someone didn't, open it for him. - (meaning that the script won't be clicked on, he will be called from the cmd and be set in the PATH variable so it can be used from every directory)

Comment: You can pass commands with `cmd /c <commads> `. See http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html for more information.